# Textures with programmable color in Rajawali

Tags: android, opengl-es, rajawali

All works great for me with Rajawali in Android, except textures.
I would like to programmatically load a transparent image as a texture, with a chessboard pattern where each black square is in fact fully transparent while each white square is just white.
I would like to use this as a texture over an object, that otherwise has diffuse and specular color properties that can be changed programmatically. So if the user has inputted the color blue, I would like the object to show a blue-white pattern.
How can I do that?
The rajawali tutorials do not really help, since for textures rajawali changed a lot in the last update. Also the Rajawali examples app does not really help, as they all seem to deal with environment maps.
What I tried was e.g.:

```
protected void initScene() {
objParser = new LoaderOBJ(mContext.getResources(), mTextureManager,        R.raw.stdblock_obj); 
try{
Texture jetTexture = new Texture("jetTexture", R.drawable.chessboardtexture);
mTextureManager.getInstance().addTexture(jetTexture);
semiglossMaterial.addTexture(jetTexture);
semiglossMaterial.setColorInfluence(0);
}catch(TextureException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

The object is rendered, but without any texture. The chessboard image does have a size power-of-2, and it is located in the right folder R.raw.stdblock_obj. It is a jpg image, but I also tried png which didn't work either.

I also tried a different approach:

```
semiglossMaterial.enableLighting(true);
semiglossMaterial.setDiffuseMethod(new DiffuseMethod.Lambert());    
phongMethod.setShininess(iShininess);            semiglossMaterial.addTexture(new Texture("jetTexture",R.drawable.chessboardtexture));
semiglossMaterial.addTexture(new AlphaMapTexture("alphaMapTex", R.drawable.simpletexture3));
semiglossMaterial.setColorInfluence(0);
```

but also this did not work.
Anyone an idea?

Comment: a query -  `R.drawable.chessboardtexture` is an image to be used as texture. But, what is purpose of `R.raw.stdblock_obj` ? Is it an image ?

Comment: R.raw.stdblock_obj is the obj file that contains the object, Kiran.

Comment: ok. From the question second para it appeared like it was an image. A suggestion: have you tried textures with color on a simple Plane primitive ? Or is this not working only for parsed objects ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add that texture as a child, a child of the .obj file, if you don´t know how many child have your .obj and the name of them, use:

```
"your3DobjectName".numChildren(),
```

then use a simple

```
for(int i = 0; i < "your3DobjectName".numChildren(); i++)
{ 
   String name = "your3DobjectName".getChildAt(i).name(); 
   Log.d("rajawali", "Name: "+name);
}
```

At this way you will know how many childs and the name of your childs declared at your obj